# How do you turn off all accessibility options in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, registry, accessibility

Is there a way in the registry or otherwise to permanently turn off or - even better - to completely remove every last bit of these incredibly annoying accessibility options in Windows 10?

I fully realise these options can be of great value to people who actually need them, to me however, they are just a complete nuisance that keeps rearing its ugly head when I need it least. So... sticky keys, huge mouse pointers, menus that pop up when I stay too long in one spot with my tablet pointer... I want all this crap thoroughly removed from my system but can't seem to find a place where I can send all this "user friendliness" to die.

Any ideas that go beyond "Ease of Access" in Settings?

Cheers!

Comment: ask this over on superuser.com - stackoverflow is for programming related questions so it doesn't fit here I am afraid.

Comment: Fair enough... I just realised 99% of my computer-related questions concern programming and Stackoverflow has been a pretty trustworthy resource for that so far. I never realised it doe shave its limitations :-)